# Prove that the sequence $u_n = as_n + bt_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ be two Cauchy sequences. Let a, b be two real constants, show that the sequence defined by $u_n = as_n + bt_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence.

Came across the question on Yahoo! Answers and want to see if my answer is correct:

Let $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ be two Cauchy sequences. Let a, b be two real constants. Then there exists $N,K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k,m > N$ with $k>m$ and for all $l,p > K$ with $l>p$ we have

$|s_k - s_m| < {\epsilon \over 2a}$, and $|t_l - t_p| < {\epsilon \over 2b}$ for all ${\epsilon \over 2a}, {\epsilon \over 2b} > 0$.

Multiply by $a,b$ respectively to obtain

$a|s_k - s_m| < {\epsilon \over 2}$, and $b|t_l - t_p| < {\epsilon \over 2}$.

Adding these two inequalities we obtain

$a|s_k - s_m| + b|t_l - t_p| < {\epsilon \over 2} + {\epsilon \over 2} = \epsilon$

Let $u_n = as_n + bt_n$, and let B = N + K. Then for all $n_1,n_2>B$ with $n_1 > n_2$ we have

$a|s_{n_1} - s_{n_2}| + b|t_{n_1} - t_{n_2}| <  \epsilon$. Thus $u_n$ is Cauchy.

Is this correct? If not, please explain precisely why. This is the type of question I might seen on an exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. I think you mean to have $|a|$ and $|b|$ in various places, and the proof won't work if $a$ or $b$ is zero; but that's an easily handled case. I think you also mean to let $\epsilon > 0$ be given at the beginning; the selection of $\epsilon$ after defining certain large numbers is backwards. As it's written, your quantifiers aren't exactly correct.